# uniform distribution for probability

Tags: statistics

> The city needs to perform some road maintenance and will rent excavator machines from a company.   Each excavator will work for at least one hour and no more than $4$ hours in a day.   The working time is evenly distributed.
>
> Given that a excavator has already worked for $2.5$ hours what is the probability that it will work at least $1$ more hour?

I know that its a uniform distribution, I just do not know how to solve the questions, I know I am looking for $\mathsf P(P>3.5 \mid P>2.5)$ but I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried so we will know what kind of help you need. Similarly, to the question you posted a few minutes ago, you need to start by looking at the definition of a CDF. This one can be done by geometry instead of integration.

Comment: i am just asking, given the information and the solution for a uniform distribution arent i just looking for when P>3.5 and less then 4 which is the upper bound? so I just need to solve the uniform distribution for 3.5?

Comment: The notation $P(P > 3.5|P > 2.5)$ is not meaningful. You seem to have used $P$ to mean two different things. Maybe $P(X > 3.5 | X > 2.5).$ Then what is $X$? Can you just find $P(X > 3.5)?$

Comment: Use [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability), event $A$ is that it will work for another hour (it will work for at least $3.5$ hours), event $B$ is that it have already worked for $2.5$ hour.  And same as in your other question, please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: i figured it out, thank you

Answer (score -1):

As we have 
P (A|B)=P [A,B]/P (B)
I,e
      P [x>3.5|x>2.5]=P [x>3.5,x>2.5]/P [x>2.5]
                               =P [x>3.5]/P [x>2.5]
since intersection of [x>3.5,x>2.5]=[x>3.5]